# How can I add functions.php functionality and keep it when updating the theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

If adding custom functionality to the `functions.php` file in WordPress, does that also mean that this would need to be updated each time that the theme needs to be updated, IF the `functions.php` is edited in the new theme update?

Are there any ways around this, to add a function filter, such as this one, but have it persist through theme updates?

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $opts = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

Answer (score 1):

> The **functions.php** file is where you add unique features to your
> WordPress theme. It can be used to hook into the core functions of
> WordPress to make your theme more modular, extensible, and functional.
> And applies only to that theme (if the theme is changed, the features
> can no longer be used)
>
> A child theme can have its own functions.php file. Adding a function
> to the child functions file is a risk-free way to modify a parent
> theme. That way, when the parent theme is updated, you don’t have to
> worry about your newly added function disappearing.

Follow this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) to learn how to create a child theme, it's pretty easy and straightforward